# PHP file get contents and '&#13;'

Tags: php, file

I am trying to ready some text from a file and for some reason there is always:
'`&#13;`' character that is added add the end of every line. The charset of the file is ASCII so I looked up ascii code and all and thsi code is not htere.

When I search on google for '`&#13;`' it searches for empty....I am guessing that this code means something but I can't even google it....

UPDATE:
I can't edit the file to remove them because user updates them.
As it is in the file, I don't see these charcters. But when I try to the read value to a variable it returns false because there is i the &13 code.
Here is when I check the response of the code:
'Notes :'

And when I check the output:
'Notes:'

The way I figured out for these extra characters is because my return array had a length of 1 more than the string I was trying to compare with.
Is there any way I can remove the code?

I tried teh str_replace() without any succes.

Thanks for your help,
Ara

Comment: So... the file contains "&#13;" on every line? Literally the characters "&#13;"? So... what? Just remove them if you don't like them? Or what else do you want to do with them?

Comment: Try opening the file with notepad++ and change the encoding of the file. You can try to convert UTF8. This may hep.

Comment: User `str_replace('&#13', '')` to remove it. Or specify your question

Comment: @deseze, I cant because the users uploads the file.

Comment: @isa, I can't do that because the user uploads it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a carriage return (\r) used in DOS files

Answer (score 0):

After I figured out what hte code means, it was easier for me to google it.

To read the code without these, I use the trim() function.

Thanks all for answering.

Answer (score -1):

use `&amp`; instead of `&` alone.

Comment: Hi, The user uploads the file so I don't have control on it.

Comment: it's you who write the url ? aren't you ?

Comment: it's you who create the url for the user to upload the file , so just replace the & par &amp ; with the file id => url="&amp;$id" (example)